# How do I see all the errors in a JS file in one place?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, webstorm, debugger

Other than manually looking for the wavy underlines to see all possible errors in a file, is there a way to see all the possible Syntax, Spelling and Scope errors in one place?

For example:

[image: screenshot of test JavaScript file]

those wavy lines under various problem spots? They become hard for me to spot with a 300 line file. I would like all those problems shown in one place, like a debugger, *without* having to run anything.

My understanding is if WebStorm can show those underlines for me, it should be able to show me all of them collected in one place.

Comment: http://getfirebug.com/javascript to debug.

Comment: Thanks, I use Chrome Debugger atm and will check into Firebug as well (been a while). However it would be nice not to have to open the browser since much of my JS is not executed there (node).

Comment: (04:25:15 AM) kiview: `View->Tool Windows -> Problems`  in IRC, `#idea-users`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the scope of the project window, to show you the files with problems only.

However, if you want to see all warnings and even more inspections, you could use the Code Inspection Tool: "Analyze -> Inspect Code..."

(on Mac, this is under `Code`->`Inspect` menu)

Example:
[image: "Analyze->Inspect Code" Sample]